# ANTLR4. How to create properly unicode range lexer rules?

Tags: antlr4

In my grammar I'd like variables to be comprised of latin, cyrillic and mandarin characters. 
For this purposes I define lexer rule, like this:
CYRILLIC_RANGE:     [\u0400–\u04FF];
this is what I see in my ANTLRWorks 2.1 output when I try to run expression against my query:
line 1:4 token recognition error at: 'н'
What am I missing?

Comment: The hyphen in your char class, `–`, seems to be a long hyphen. It should be: `-` (ASCII `0x2D`).

Comment: As an alternative use the new [ANTLR 4.7 Unicode block support](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md), e.g. `\p{Lu}` for uppercase letters. Of course this requires to build your own ANTLR4 jar from source.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are missing, as this seems to be working for me here. Have you tried the other range syntax? Both of these should be equivalent.

```
CYRILLIC_RANGE : [\u0400-\u04FF] ;
CYRILLIC_RANGE : '\u0400'..'\u04FF' ;
```